# Laravel RedirectResponse::getData() error

Tags: php, laravel

Has anyone encountered this error before? Happens when making an API request from an external app using the new laravel HTTP client with an invalid API key.

If I make the same request with Postman (with invalid key), I get the desired 401 instead of an internal server error.

The app that is generating the error is running Laravel 6.

**BadMethodCallException**

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::getData()
>   vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:50

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using to actually make a request?

Comment: "The app that is generating the error is running laravel 6.

BadMethodCallException" <- You have to send same request verb (GET, POST...) which you are sending from postman environment.

Answer (score 1):

Appears as though the headers were not defaulting to application/json and was therefor getting redirected to login.